# Bayseian +Pymc. How to call a integration while defining a model in pymc

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc, mcmc

[image]I am new to pymc . I am having difficulties in defining  the model in my code.
Model involve a integration over step length . I am confused because I don't know if I can define a function as deterministic one with variables from data and uniform random number(which are H(Hubble constant) and O(some constant) ) ,). All the examples I have found on internet,in those examples  models involve only linear or something in which one don't have to call or define a function.I know python in extent so that I can solve this problem without using pymc but what is fun if I can't do it in pymc.I am trying to learn by reading available codes ,but without good explanation I am too confused now.

"This is error"

```
This is the error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "5.py", line 21, in <module>
    def y_model(z=z_true,a=H,b=O ): # this is my model like in on line examples (y=mx+c kind of )
  File "/home/gaurav/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc/InstantiationDecorators.py", line 250, in deterministic
    return instantiate_n(__func__)
  File "/home/gaurav/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc/InstantiationDecorators.py", line 243, in instantiate_n
    return Deterministic(parents=parents, **kwds)
  File "/home/gaurav/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc/PyMCObjects.py", line 442, in __init__
    verbose=verbose)
  File "/home/gaurav/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc/Node.py", line 219, in __init__
    Node.__init__(self, doc, name, parents, cache_depth, verbose=verbose)
  File "/home/gaurav/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc/Node.py", line 129, in __init__
    self.parents = parents
  File "/home/gaurav/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc/Node.py", line 152, in _set_parents
    self.gen_lazy_function()
  File "/home/gaurav/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc/PyMCObjects.py", line 453, in gen_lazy_function
    self._value.force_compute()
  File "LazyFunction.pyx", line 257, in pymc.LazyFunction.LazyFunction.force_compute (pymc/LazyFunction.c:2409)
  File "5.py", line 22, in y_model
    nd1=(1+z_true)*integrate.quad(fun,0,z_true,O)/H
  File "/home/gaurav/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 311, in quad
    points)
  File "/home/gaurav/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 360, in _quad
    if (b != Inf and a != -Inf):
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

```html
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
import pymc



# Create some convenience routines for plotting
#@pymc.stochastic(observed=True)
z_true,u_true,deltau_true=np.loadtxt('sn_data.dat',usecols=(1,2,3),unpack=True)
sigma_true=np.power(deltau_true,-2)
#print('1',len(z_true),len(u_true))
H=pymc.Uniform('H',40.0,100.0)
O=pymc.Uniform('O',0.13,0.32)
@pymc.deterministic   
def fun(z=z_true,o=O):#this is integrand for model 
    nd=3.0*(10**5)/(np.sqrt( (1-o)+o*(1+z)**3))
    return(nd) 
@pymc.deterministic    
def y_model(z=z_true,a=H,b=O ): # this is my model like in on line examples (y=mx+c kind of )
    nd1=(1+z)*integrate.quad(fun,0,z,b)/a
    return(5*np.log(nd1)+25) 

    
@pymc.stochastic(plot=False)
def tau(c=deltau_true):
    return (np.power(c,-2))    
    
data=pymc.Normal('data',mu=y_model,sigma=sigma_true,value=u_true,observed=True)    
sampler=pymc.MCMC(data)

sampler = pymc.MCMC([H,O,y_model,tau,u_true,z_true])
sampler.use_step_method(pymc.AdaptiveMetropolis, [H,O])
sampler.sample(iter=10000)    
pymc.Matplot.plot(sampler)
plt.show()
```

Comment: pls help .I am stuck on this for very long time.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is not working in your model? It is not clear from your question. One issue is that your `tau` stochastic does not have a `value` argument, which is required.

Comment: I have added a image file. feed Equation 4.4  to equation 4.3 ,that will give the model.

Comment: And I don't understand why should and how I will give  this "value  " ??

Comment: All stochastics must have values. Recall from the [PyMC docs](https://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc/modelbuilding.html#the-stochastic-class) that a stochastic represents an unknown variable we are trying to estimate, and whose value we are iteratively drawing values for.

Comment: okk ... Other than what are the mistakes in y_model ?? Because when I am using a linear function to just check my code,It's is not giving any  error .But for integration ,it's showing error .

Comment: Its difficult to tell without seeing any error output.

Comment: Your call to `integrate.quad` appears to be invalid. You can check the inputs using `pdb`. Looks like you are passing an array where a scalar is expected.